# Material UI - Webpack error for Radio button

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I'm trying to add a simple RadioGroup in my app using Material UI, but for some reason there's a problem in the render phase. I created my own `webpack.config.js` and I think that could be the problem.

The React code is really simple:

```
...
<RadioGroup value={value} onChange={onChangeValue}>
   {choices.map((choice) => (
      <FormControlLabel
          key={choice.id}
          value={choice.value}
          control={<Radio />}
          label={choice.value}
       />
   ))}
</RadioGroup>
...
```

The console shows me this error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided
('http://localhost:3000/351d4e65888594b86254d833e9182a1f.js') is not a valid name.
```

And if I open that file, it returns this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import createSvgIcon from '../../utils/createSvgIcon';
/**
 * @ignore - internal component.
 */

export default createSvgIcon( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("path", {
  d: "M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0
18c-4.42 0-8-3.58-8-8s3.58-8 8-8 8 3.58 8 8-3.58 8-8 8z"
}), 'RadioButtonUnchecked');
```

My `webpack.config.js` is made like this:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: "./",
    hot: true,
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.[hash].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    modules: [__dirname, "src", "node_modules"],
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", ".ts"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png|svg|jpg|gif$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer myself, I just had to edit the `webpack.config.js` using the new *asset* module that comes with webpack5:

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png|jpg|gif$/,
        use: ["file-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
...
```